# Repeated AWS EC2 Autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I was looking at the AWS EC2 Auto-Scaling with Cloud Watch feature.

What I cannot glean is if the auto scaling can be applied only once or repeatedly? I think only once though.

E.g. scale from 2 to 4 max if, say, 60% cpu reached.

Then, what if, having gone from 2 to 4, and then 60% cpu reached again according to Cloud Watch target rules, can we reapply autoscaling again?

I saw a **"step"** option, but that seems to work with different target values. Could the step have repeated 60% configuration or does it need 60, 70% and so on? This aspect is not entirely clear.

Or is such an iterative approach simply not possible? Implying one needs to re-baseline the initial allocations? I think not based on the step approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autoscaling will be triggered by CloudWatch alarms when your alarm will breach your threshold.

So if your policy is to add 50% capacity when average CPU across the fleet is above 60% for more than 15min, the alarm will trigger a change in your scaling group, increasing the value of your "desired capacity" property, let's say going from 2 to 3 instances. Autoscaling will then react and bring the fleet to "desired capacity"

If, later, the same alarm is still on, a new change will be triggered to your scaling group, bringing desired capacity to 4.  Then AutoScaling will create EC2 instances to bring your fleet to the new desired capacity.

And so on.

Of course, you do not want to increase the fleet size above your budget.  So you can define a MAX fleet size, that AutoScaling will never go above.  If your max fleet size is 3, the second alarm in my example will leave desired capacity as it is (3) because new desired capacity > max capacity.  This will end up the scaling process.

To go back to normal, you must also create scale in policies, in addition of your scale out policies : i.e. when the average CPU on my fleet is below 15% for 1h, let's remove an instance.  Your CloudWatch alarm will trigger, causing a change in the desired capacity of your fleet and AutoScaling will adjust (kill instances) to go to the new desired capacity value.

Of course, you do not want AutoScaling to kill the last instance from your fleet (going from desired capacity of 1 to desired capacity of 0), so, similarly to a MAX Capacity value, you also define a MIN capacity, i.e. the minimum number of instances to keep in your fleet, whatever alarm are triggering and trying to change the desired capacity.

Comment: 3 to 4 is not 50% though.

Comment: In your example it sounds like it is base on the original baseline.

Comment: About : 3 to 4. 3 + 50% = 4.5. Technically AutoScaling can not create half instances so it will go to 4 or 5. I would need to verify the doc which one is correct. Rounding down is better for your budget so I think it is the policy implemented. Pending being proven wrong by the doc

Comment: The original baseline is desired capacity at the time you create the group. After that desired capacity will change. CloudWatch alarms, API calls or console are all valid ways to change the desired capacity. AutoScaling will always do its best to bring your fleet size to the desired capacity. Desired capacity will never go below minimum capacity or above maximum capacity

Comment: But my second point is more relevant. The rule remains active and is based on 3. And then on 4 or 5.